# How do I pass more than one JSON parameters like headers to Post Request in VBA?

Tags: json, python-3.x, excel, vba, upload

I am able to attach a header but I am also trying to pass the parameters in form of dictionary to get the PostRequest in VBA.

```
**parameters to pass**
headers = {some headers}
files = {'upload_file': 'myfile.csv'}
data = {"key1": "value1","key2": "value2"}

*I need to do something similar like this as we do in other language like python*
requests.post(url, headers=header, data=data, files=files)

**vba code** 
With req
        .Open "POST", reqURL, False
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "Application/json"
        .send
End With
```

I am using MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 as a req variable

Comment: `.send data` will send your JSON in the request body

Comment: @TimWilliams: Thanks. But how can I add multiple JSON. In this case that would be files{} and data{}. I tried but .send accepts only 1 parameter. I am not sure if we can attach .send multiple times. It says that "the method cannot be called after the send method has been called"

Comment: If you want to send both data and files then I think you need to set the content-type to multi-part and it's more involved.  For example see: http://www.ericphelps.com/scripting/samples/reference/web/http_post.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try concatenating the parameters with `;`

```vb
    Dim fso As Object, ts As Object, data As String, files As String
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.opentextfile("myfile.csv", 1)
    files = "{'upload_file': '" & ts.readAll & "'}"
    ts.Close

    data = "{'key1': 'value1','key': 'value2'}"

    With req
        .Open "POST", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "Application/json"
        .send "data=" & data & ";files=" & files
        Debug.Print .responseText
    End With
```

The python code is posting multipart/form-data so it gets a bit more complicated

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub postjson()

    Const reqURL = "http://clougo.at/api/trading"
    Const CSV_FILE = "input.csv"
    Const token = "1|WZeEXorNG6qWVmr8zj80PrkrhiFcMupj1NMwj7Nh"
    
    Dim data As Object, key
    Set data = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    data.Add "product", "POWER"
    data.Add "valid_until", "2021-09-07"
    data.Add "market_area", "DE"
    
    ' generate boundary
    Dim BOUNDARY, s As String, n As Integer
    For n = 1 To 16: s = s & Chr(65 + Int(Rnd * 25)): Next
    BOUNDARY = s & CDbl(Now)

    Dim part As String, ado As Object
    For Each key In data.keys
        part = part & "--" & BOUNDARY & vbCrLf
        part = part & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""" & key & """" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        part = part & data(key) & vbCrLf
    Next
    ' filename
    part = part & "--" & BOUNDARY & vbCrLf
    part = part & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""upload_file""; filename=""" & CSV_FILE & """" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    
    ' read csv file as binary
    Dim csv
    Set ado = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    ado.Type = 1 'binary
    ado.Open
    ado.LoadFromFile CSV_FILE
    ado.Position = 0
    csv = ado.read
    ado.Close

    ' combine part, csv , end
    ado.Open
    ado.Position = 0
    ado.Type = 1 ' binary
    ado.Write ToBytes(part)
    ado.Write csv
    ado.Write ToBytes(vbCrLf & "--" & BOUNDARY & "--")
    ado.Position = 0

    Dim req As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    With req
        .Open "POST", reqURL, False
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "Application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & token
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & BOUNDARY
        .send ado.read
        Debug.Print .responseText
    End With

End Sub

Function ToBytes(str As String) As Variant

    Dim ado As Object
    Set ado = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    ado.Open
    ado.Type = 2 ' text
    ado.Charset = "_autodetect"
    ado.WriteText str
    ado.Position = 0
    ado.Type = 1
    ToBytes = ado.read
    ado.Close

End Function
```

Comment: The concatenating part was done but I am still getting a response status of 401. I have a very well working code in python, but I am not able to make it workable in VBA. I am not sure, but I think I have all the ingredients required to post a response to the given URL. BTW, I have attached the entire code. I don't think I have missed any parameters. Can you see any missing in my VBA script?

Comment: @kulekhaki What was the responseText ?

Comment: the response status was still 401 after I applied your suggestion to my full code. kindly refer to the full code that I have submitted

Comment: @kulekhani 401 is Unauthorized - the request lacks valid authentication credentials. Where is the documentation for the API ?

Comment: Actually the credentials that I have included here is same as with the python code and in python I am getting a response status of 200 and with that, the upload of csv data is confirmed from the other end. So, where did I go wrong? I am not able to get the API documentation. Can you help? you can use any csv file to check the code in python BTW.

Comment: @kulekhali In your python code do you have a space between bearer and token . in vba you don't  `"Bearer" & token`

Comment: That saved my day. You were right. THANKS much. But there is a glitch. The response from VBA is 200 now but the server side has not been receiving the post that was sent. Its strange. It works fine when ever I make a post request (with csv data) using python. I will be thankful if you can find any luck in this :)

Comment: @kulekhani What headers  ie `{some headers}`, do you have in the python code ?

Comment: kindly refer to the python code that I have put as an answer

Comment: @kulek I have updated my answer. Your python code has a parameter `valid_unil` is that correct ?

Comment: YES. it seems like "until" but it works anyways

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim req As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim reqURL As String
    Dim fso, ts As Object
    Dim data As String, files As String
    
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\mypath\input.csv", 1)
    files = "{'upload_file': '" & ts.ReadAll & "'}"
    'Debug.Print files
    ts.Close
    
    data = "{'product':'POWER','valid_unil':'2021-09-07','market_area':'DE'}"
    'Debug.Print data
    
    reqURL = "http://clougo.at/api/trading"
    
    token = "1|WZeEXorNG6qWVmr8zj80PrkrhiFcMupj1NMwj7Nh"
    
    With req
        .Open "POST", reqURL, False
        '.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer" & token
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "Application/json"
        .send "data=" & data & ";files=" & files
    End With
    
    Debug.Print req.Status

End Sub
```

the response is 401

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

here is the working python code

```
import requests


url = "http://clougo.at/api/trading"
csv_file = "input.csv"

auth_token = "1|WZeEXorNG6qWVmr8zj80PrkrhiFcMupj1NMwj7Nh"
header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token, 'Accept': 'application/json'}

files = {'upload_file': open(csv_file, 'rb')}

data = {
"product": "POWER",
"valid_unil": "2021-09-07",
"market_area": "DE"
}
r = requests.post(url, headers=header, data=data, files=files)

print(r)
```